# write tool-tip that can be invoked for ay html element. should consist of 3 elements title, content, Okay button

Tags: button, tooltip

I really need help. I am unable to find any examples to this particular problem. I have spent many hours and really want to give up. We have never covered this in the program I am in and I really do want to learn even how to begin. I spent 5 plus hours  working on this and came up with a solution that worked but since it did not follow all rules it was not accepted. We have not covered tooltips so I’m not sure how to go about this.

The question is to write a tool-tip that can be invoked for any html element on a given page. The preferred position can be viewed left right or bottom of html element. Should contain title, Content, Okay button that will dissolve after user clicks the okay button.

api to be used is

$('#HTML element').showToolTip ( {
    Title: 'This is the title'
    Content: 'This is the content'
    onApprove: function() {
      //to be called after Okay button is clicked.
    }
} );

Answer (score 0):

showToolTip is a jQuery plugin to create a tool-tip-style alert popup which can be attached to any element when triggered.

It provides a callback function which will be fired when the user clicks on the Okay button inside the alert popup.

The plugin grabs dimensional information about the popup, host element and the viewport width and height to calculate in which direction to show the alert popup. For example it automatically re position the alert popup if TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, LEFT doesn't have enough space.

[Visit this link to see how to use](https://www.jqueryscript.net/tooltip/tooltip-alert-popup.html)